# Modify sysctl parameters inside docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, swarm, sysctl

I am running a 3 node swarm cluster and trying to launch services with

docker stack deploy

Below is my compose file

```
services:

  nginx:
   image: nginx:latest
   networks:
     - til-prod-network
   volumes:
     - type: bind
       source: /tmp/nginx/nginx.conf
       target: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
   ports:
     - 83:80
  depends_on:
    - BLUE
  deploy:
    replicas: 1
    update_config:
    parallelism: 1
    delay: 10s
  restart_policy:
    condition: on-failure
  placement:
    constraints:
      - node.role == manager
  resources:
    reservations:
      memory: 4096M
    limits:
      memory: 4096M

  BLUE:
    image: dtr.xxx.xxx/cmdb:v1.26
    sysctls:
      net.core.somaxconn: 4096
    networks:
     - til-prod-network
    deploy:
     replicas: 2
     update_config:
     parallelism: 1
     delay: 10s
    placement:
      constraints:
        - node.role == worker
    resources:
      reservations:
         memory: 2048M
      limits:
         memory: 2048M

 networks:
   til-prod-network:
      external: true
```

But when i deploy this via docker stack deploy, it gives me error of "Unsupported option sysctls".

Docker docs says same.

What solution should i implement to modify sysctl inside containers when running in swarm mode.

Answer (score 2):

Sysctl support for docker swarm cluster [added](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/37701) in Docker [19.03.0](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/releases).

Answer (score 1):

1. version compose file must be 3.
2. swarm will ignore key sysctls anyway

For now, no correct solutions exist